# Javascript For Loop with conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

I am looking to use a for loop to accomplish the following.

I will have a defined set of values in an array, a set of hex values as default colors for a chart. I want to grab a defined number of those values using the loop with 2 options.

1. If the # of values in the defined set of colors is less than the # of values requested, once it hits the last, it starts back at one and continues the loop.
2. Less important but could be helpful is starting by grabbing values at any index in the set of default values and using the same conditions as #1, in that if it gets to the last value in the colors array it would cycle back to the start and continue going.

Below is a start of the code I have along with small values to show what I am looking for.

```
var defaultColors = ["#90CAF9","#B39DDB","#7E57C2","#78909C","#AED581"] ;
var chartData = [12,24,30,40,15,23,35] ;

var dynamicColors = function (a) {
    var colors = [];
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        colors.push(defaultColors[i]);
    }
    return colors;
}
```

And the call for the colors

```
backgroundColor: dynamicColors(chartData.length),
```

In the above example there are more data points than color values requiring the loop to start back at the begin of the color array.

Expected output for #1 just looping from the beginning of the array.

```
["#90CAF9","#B39DDB","#7E57C2","#78909C","#AED581","#90CAF9","#B39DDB"]
```

Expected output for #2 - Specifying a starting index.

```
["#7E57C2","#78909C","#AED581","#90CAF9","#B39DDB","#7E57C2","#78909C"]
```

Comment: *"...the # of values..."* What does the hash: `#` represent? Is it: *"...the **hex number** of values..."*, or is it *"...the **total number** of values..."*, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [modulo (aka remainder)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator `%` with the list length to loop continue looping around the list:

```js
var defaultColors = ["#90CAF9", "#B39DDB", "#7E57C2", "#78909C", "#AED581"];
var chartData = [12, 24, 30, 40, 15, 23, 35];

var dynamicColors = function(a) {
  var colors = [];
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    colors.push(defaultColors[i % defaultColors.length]);
  }
  return colors;
}

console.log(dynamicColors(10))
```

To start at a different location, just add it to `i` and use the mod operator again:

```js
var defaultColors = ["#90CAF9", "#B39DDB", "#7E57C2", "#78909C", "#AED581"];
var chartData = [12, 24, 30, 40, 15, 23, 35];

var dynamicColors = function(a, start) {
  var colors = [];
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    colors.push(defaultColors[(i + start) % defaultColors.length]);
  }
  return colors;
}

console.log(dynamicColors(7, 3)) // seven values starting at index 3
```